# UITableView scrolling UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

How can i scroll my UINavigationBar according to a UITableView scroll,i mean:

- When the user scrolls the UITableView down,the UINavigationBar should scroll with the UITableView and disappear;
- When the user scrolls the UITableView up,the UINavigationBar should stay fixed on the top of the view.

I want a similar effect to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955974/uisearchbar-on-the-top-of-uitableview-which-can-hide-but-stay-close-to-uinavigat) but instead of a UISearchBar i need to do the same effect with a UINavigationBar,i've already tried the code from the link.Please any piece of code or source code will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `UINavigationBar` provided by a `UINavigationController`? If so the docs for [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state you must never change the navigationBars frame or bounds

Comment: It is a new UINavigationBar.The problem is how?I've already tried to make the UINavigationBar frame static when the user scroll the UITableView but it didn't worked.

Comment: To make it stay still implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` on the object acting as the tableViewDelegate and then change the frame of the navigationBar in that

Comment: I did not use an navigation bar but added a uiview instead. I also used scrollViewDidScroll delegate but my approach was a bit different. You might want to check the source code below https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2c0zw6yvchaia5/FailedBanks.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the code for [this library](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar). It behaves a little differently (it mimicks the Chrome ios7 app), but you can easily rework the navbar handling to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting post that might help.
http://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uinavigationbar-that-scrolls-away/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by hiding the `navigationBar` of the `ViewController` and adding a fake `UINavigationBar` into the Header of the first section of the `tableView`.

Comment: I've already thought on that but how can i make the UINavigationBar static when the user is in the top of the UITableView and still scrolling up?Check the images from the link that i provided.

Comment: Hmm... I see your point.  Possibly, instead of hiding the navigation bar you could access the scrollView delegate methods of UITableViewController and sue the offset of the scroll view to adjust the frame (or centre point) of the UINavigationBar.  That way you can move it up if necessary but not move it down below its normal position.  I've never tried this though.