# Keeping UISeachBar from dissappearing when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, uisearchbar

**PROBLEM**

I want to keep the UISearchBar at the top of my UITableview, but it scrolls away with the list when I scroll down.

I found this post and followed it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870085/locking-a-uisearchbar-to-the-top-of-a-uitableview-like-game-center)

It told me to use this code

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
//    UISearchBar *searchBar = searchDisplayController.searchBar;
searchBar = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
rect.origin.y = MAX(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
searchBar.frame = rect;
}
```

I may have missed something, but this method is called but the UISearchBar stil disappears.

Comment: That should be MIN, and the link is about game center's toolbar, which is locked to the bottom of the navigationBar.  You want a bar that scrolls with the scrollview.

Comment: Are you sure that the method is being called and that searchBar isn't nil?

Comment: Have you tried adding the searchbar outside the scrollview so that it stays top?

Comment: @CodaFi Sorry i had it as MIN, i just want the searchbar to stay under the navigation bar when the user scrolls. so they can search no matter where they are in the list and not just at the top

Comment: Put the search bar outside the scrollview as @LuisOscar said then.

Comment: @LuisOscar How do i put it on the outside? Just declare it on the outside? Sorry, i am kind of new to this

Comment: @fbernardo it actually seems like searchBar is nil....any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a searchDisplayController connected in IB?

Comment: You are not doing this programatically are you? What i mean is that, if you just want the searchbar to stay there and the contents to scroll down, all you have to do is in the interface builder on the view of that window to make sure the uisearchbar is not nested inside the scroll view so that it doesnt scroll it down. if you added the searchbar on the interface builder then it cant be nil cuz it is automatically being allocated, you might have the pointer not pointing to this one or the contents might be nil. Like bernardo suggests make sure u r linking it in the IB

Comment: @LuisOscar i will answer this because your solution was right.

Comment: @LuisOscar Thanks by the way for you patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution was A LOT easier than i expected. All i had to do in IB was drag the SearchBar out of the View so it was no longer nested.

Comment: It's incredible, but this situation happens to me in iOS 7 and Xcode 5. Simple solution.

Comment: what of using xcode 7 ( where you can't find it in object library ) and UISearchController ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a document from apple developer forum,named "advanced_scroll_view_techniques.pdf",that will help you.

docs: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/104_advanced_scroll_view_techniques.pdf

sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html