# UITableview header not shown again if scrolled up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have UITableview Controller, who has search bar in header. When i scrolled up the table view and it bounce. But the search bar hides. when i scroll down then the search bar shown. can any one tell me how can i show the search bar again?

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work smoothly:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;//Change as per your table header hight
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
        //scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, -[self.tableView  contentInset].top);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Here is screen shot for view before scrolling:
[image]

And this is wrong view, After scrolling:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your viewForHeaderInSection Method ?

Comment: This header isn't section header.. its tableview's header.

Comment: Here is the code for section
`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==0)
    {
        return 35.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 25.0;
    }
}`

Comment: what is that 40 hardcoded ? what happen if you make it to 200

Comment: Its header height it is working but i am changing this in viewdidscroll so that's why, it is not smooth

Comment: If i changed the value to 200 the if conditions will not work.

Comment: Maybe, this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870085/locking-a-uisearchbar-to-the-top-of-a-uitableview-like-game-center

Comment: no its not working :(

Comment: why have you keep commented that if logic in your cde ? is it not working or you forgot to uncomment

Comment: @Alok its working for me but it is slow and jerky. i want a smooth bounce of tableview.

Comment: ok how about setting contentOffset to No , and use your custom animation ?

Comment: still its jerky and too much fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about disabling animation to off and put custom animation like this:

also make your sure to have same sectionHeader height using MAcro. i have still doubt in your one of comment saying 35 or 25.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
            CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;//Change as per your table header hight
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                      animations: ^{
                          scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
                      }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                      }
        ];
            } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
                CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, -[self.tableView  contentInset].top);


[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                  animations: ^{
                      [self.tableView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:NO];
                  }completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                  }
    ];
            }
}
```

Comment: It still hides behind the view

Comment: I have commented that lines but still facing the same issue

Comment: can you just try for a moment with 40.0f at every place for heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: I figured out a way thanks for the help it help alot :)

Comment: vote up the question please if you think it help someone else too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  
{  
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;  
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {  
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);  
    }  
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {  
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);  
    }  
}
```

but your problem is,your tableview header is not 40,it's 35 or 25,that means your tableview can't setup a correct number to the inset,try change 40 to correct header height.

Comment: Its not a section header.